# pygame camera not closing

Tags: python, pygame, spyder

The camera is still running even after the following code is stopped the execution. I could see the camera lights on in my laptop (using Windows 10 Home). I had tried to close the camera in task manager too but still camera is not closing.

The program has run successfully. I could see a photo saved in the destination.

How to close the laptop inbuilt-camera?

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera

pygame.camera.init()
pygame.camera.list_cameras() #Camera detected or not
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(0,(640,480))
cam.start()
img = cam.get_image()
pygame.image.save(img,r"sd.jpg")
```

I am running the program in anaconda spyder. After I restart the kernel the camera is getting off but once the program is run, the camera gets on (not able to off)

had tried it in jupyter notebook too, still same problem.

Windows10.

Comment: Have you tried including pygame.quit() after cam.stop()?

Comment: yes, after seeing your comment I tried it, still camera light is on.

Comment: Are you able to run the code you shared without errors? I run into an issue with line6, where pygame.camera.Camera has 0 as its first argument. Can you alternatively try this and let me know if you still have an issue:     
     
camlist = pygame.camera.list_cameras()     
if camlist:     
 cam = pygame.camera.Camera(camlist[0],(640,480))

Comment: yes, am able to run, followed a tutorial from the below link to overcome the error that you had said https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/160

Comment: Weird. I am able to run it without issues on my machine and the camera exits upon completion. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: have you tried it in anaconda spyder?

Comment: No, I used native python on my laptop running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

After saving the image, call `stop()` method.

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera

pygame.camera.init()
pygame.camera.list_cameras() #Camera detected or not
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(0,(640,480))
cam.start()
img = cam.get_image()
pygame.image.save(img,r"sd.jpg")
cam.stop()
```

Comment: I had tried the cam.stop()  , but the camera light is still on.